# MariaDB INSERT INTO FROM SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Below  is the block I am trying to execute, the documentation says this should work but instead I am met with an error that states "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Location_Inventory_Column (`Aisle`, `Name`)
SELECT `Aisle`, `Name` ' at line 2"

~Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO Location_Inventory_Column (`Aisle`, `Name`)
SELECT `Aisle`, `Name` FROM TMPTableImport
```

Table Inserting Into:

```
CREATE TABLE `Location_Inventory_Column` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Aisle` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Description` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Disabled` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

TMPTable contains only Aisle and Name columns (See image)

[TMPTABLE Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itg4f.png)

Comment: Delimiter (`;` by default) which finalizes `START TRANSACTION` statement is lost.

Comment: Akina, that was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Akina the statement "START TRANSACTION" was the cause as it did not have a delimiter following the semicolon.

Comment: Also, you are probably missing a `;` at the end of the `INSERT..SELECT..`

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the single quotes in the Location_Inventory_Column (`Aisle`, `Name`) like this:
Location_Inventory_Column (Aisle, Name)

Comment: There are no single quotes. These are backticks.

Comment: I tried removing the backticks with no luck... I used them to define the columns because Name is actually a function and I wanted to discern the difference.